# MvvmCross binding iOS Gestures

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm searching a way how can i bind ios gesture like UILongPressGestureRecognizer to ICommand or MvxCommand in MvvmCross, thanks.

PS : I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961000/mvvmcross-gesturerecognized-binding-to-viewmodel-action/19769985#19769985) but i can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Which bit of the example can't you figure out? If you replace `Tap` with `LongPress` then what does/doesn't work - are there compile errors? Or runtime exceptions?

Comment: i added the class LongPressBehaviour and BehaviourExtensions but when i make label.LongPress(); it does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

From the example you found and from the current MVVM Cross source I did the following

```
public static class MvxBehaviourExtensions
{
    public static MvxLongPressGestureRecognizerBehaviour LongPress(this UIView view)
    {
        var toReturn = new MvxLongPressGestureRecognizerBehaviour(view);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MvxLongPressGestureRecognizerBehaviour
    : MvxGestureRecognizerBehavior<UILongPressGestureRecognizer>
{
    protected override void HandleGesture(UILongPressGestureRecognizer gesture)
    {
        // Long press recognizer fires continuously. This will ensure we fire
        // the command only once. Fire as soon as gesture is recognized as
        // a long press.
        if (gesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        {
            FireCommand();
        }
    }

    public MvxLongPressGestureRecognizerBehaviour(UIView target)
    {
        var lp = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleGesture);

        AddGestureRecognizer(target, lp);
    }
}
```

and to bind

```
set.Bind(this.LongPress()).For(lp => lp.Command).To(c => c.DoTheStuffCommand);
```